# What is the asyncNeedsTemporalSigner flag?

Tags: typescript, solana, metaplex

While implementing gumdrop candy machine minting on my own front end I came across the `asyncNeedsTemporalSigner` flag that seems to split the users path in two.

What is this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asyncNeedsTemporalSigner` in gumdrop is used to identify if OTP has been activated.
OTP can be used for the [Distribution Methods](https://docs.metaplex.com/airdrops/create-gumdrop#distribution-method) SMS and E-Mail. It can not properly be used for discord, wallets and manual

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If I use the "wallets" distribution method and not SMS or email, what would NeedsTemporalSigner be? And what is a Temporal signer?

Comment: Not 100% sure. I think NeedsTemporalSigner should be false in case of wallets distribution method.